# How to configure and use multiple ssh RSA keys with Keychain help

Tags: ssh, keychain

I am looking for a solution that would automatically load multiple RSA keys at login, some of them having passwords stored in the Keychain.

Example: first keys would be obviously in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and let's say that the second cone would be in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.2`.

I want them to be loaded automatically, without having to enter their passwords.

Comment: What do you mean by loaded? If the keys are password protected you'll have to enter the password at least once. Then you can choose to save the password to Keychain however.

Comment: So, how to I add the key to the keychain in a persistent mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh-agent` can do this: use `ssh-add -K path/to/key` to store the passphrase for the key in your Keychain. Whenever you do something requiring that key you won't be prompted for your password, provided the Keychain is unlocked.

[This article](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/~aia21/osx/leopard-ssh.html) gives more information, as does [this related ServerFault question](https://superuser.com/questions/88470/how-to-use-mac-os-x-keychain-with-ssh-keys).